# How to stage multiple files in git with the same name

Tags: git

I have a Project with multiple pom.xml files inside. The folder structure looks something like this:

```
project:
        pom.xml
        serviceA:
                 pom.xml
        serviceB:
                 pom.xml
```

I now change each pom.xml file and want to stage all of the files. I figured out, that i can do it in two commands:

```
git add */pom.xml
git add pom.xml
```

Is there any way to do this with only one git add command?

Comment: `git add */pom.xml pom.xml`  

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+add+files+recursively

Comment: `git add **/pom.xml` makes the current shell expand `**`; for Bash `shopt -s globstar` is required. `git add "**/pom.xml"` makes Git expand `**`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try Below Format

```
git add */pom.xml pom.xml
```